# ListDensityPlot: How to show blank space where no data exists, instead of interpolation

Tags: plotting

When plotting data with `ListDensityPlot`, 'empty' points in a grid are interpolated, even when `InterpolationOrder` is set to zero. This gives awkward triangular shapes, and implies that information exists for that part of the graph, as around `x=1,y=1` below.

```
Data = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 3}};
ListDensityPlot[Data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.5}, {-0.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

**Is there a way to show blank space instead?**

Of course it is possible to just add zeroes wherever there are empty tiles (example below), but this is hacky and would require quite some effort for patchy data files.

```
Data2 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 3}};
ListDensityPlot[Data2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.5}, {-0.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Zero is a perfectly valid data value, and as such you can't expect it to be taken as missing data.  I don't know if it will give you what you want, but you might try `Null`.

Answer (score 1):

If the row and column values are integers in your data, the most convenient way to insert zeros for non-existent row/column combinations is to transform your input data into a  [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
ClearAll[toSparseArray, dataRange]

toSparseArray = SparseArray[{#2, #} + 1 -> #3 & @@@ #, 
         1 + Max /@ Transpose[#[[All, {2, 1}]] + 1]] &;

dataRange = {-.5, .5} + # & /@ Reverse[MinMax /@ 
    Transpose@toSparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] - 1] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
ListDensityPlot[toSparseArray @ Data, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, DataRange -> dataRange @ Data]
```

[image]

```
Data3 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 1,  4}};

Row @ {ListDensityPlot[Data3, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.5}, {-0.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  ListDensityPlot[toSparseArray @ Data3, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     Mesh -> All, DataRange -> dataRange @ Data3, ImageSize -> Medium]}
```

[image]